# How to assert AssertionError java?

Tags: java, junit

How can we assert an `AssertionError` with JUnit in Java?

I have some code:

```
public void do(){
 throw new AssertionError("...");
}
```

In my unit test for `do`, I want to assert that this gets thrown.

I tried things like `assertThrows(AssertionError.class, ...)` but that doesnt work.

Comment: What didn't work in ```assertThrows(AssertionError.class, ...)```?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `AssertionError` is an exception type. In your JUnit 4 test, you can assert on the expected exception like this ...

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void whenExceptionThrown_thenRuleIsApplied() {
    exceptionRule.expect(AssertionError.class);
    exceptionRule.expectMessage("Expected Message Here");

   // testing the code 
}
```